# Show last time fields were updated

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I have been using Grafana for simple temperature monitoring and love it!, in my case I have the 1-wire temperature sensors which are getting fed to influxDB where it feeds the address of the sensor (e.g. serial) and the temperature value.

I did this so that I could expand the system, and add Aliases later on if needed. What I would love to be able to do though is to have a quick and easy way to see when a sensor last sent an update. I know I could use alerts, but since some sensors will be on and off over time, i thought it might be easier to be able to do something like show a panel for each sensor, and the time/date it was last updated.

I am not sure how to best do this though, as all the panels are designed from what I can see to show the time series data (e.g. value) rather than the time/date updated.

Is there an easy way to do this, or would anyone have any pointers which may be useful?

Cheers!

Comment: Assuming you are using something like Stats panel, if you'll change Fields in Panel options from Numeric fields, to All fields, you should be able to see last time of update. Is that what you want?